# Assert is hanging instead of failing CukeJS test

Tags: assert, cucumberjs

I have the following assertion...

```
        promise.then(function() {
                  assert.ok(browser.query(addForm), "It should have the add form");
          callback();
            })
```

But when I try to see it go red, instead I get...

```
Possibly unhandled AssertionError: It should have the add form
```

and the test suite just fails to go any farther

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber.js seems to have issues if anything is thrown within functions. I'm not sure which assertion framework your using, but I ran into a similar issue using Chai expects inside of a callback that I passed to `then()`. I worked around the issue by pulling the expect outside of the callback as shown [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/876#issuecomment-50633583).

**Edit, including code from link:**

For instance, if you were using Chai and your code looked like this:

```
element(by.tagName('body')).getText().then(function (text) {
  text = doSomethingSpecial(text);
  expect(text).to.equal('something');
});
```

You could modify your code using a library that understood promises (such as chai-as-promised in this case) so that it would look like:

```
var text = element(by.tagName('body')).getText().then(function (text) {
  return doSomethingSpecial(text);
});
expect(text).to.eventually.equal('something');
```

Comment: Can you copy the code example from your link, in case the link ever expires?